# Getting empty List by converting properties into List

Tags: c#, xml, properties

I have the following property Class:

```
 public class Ctas
    {
        private string _CodAgrup;
        public string CodAgrup
        {
            get { return _CodAgrup; }
            set { _CodAgrup = value; }
        }
        private string _NumCta;

        public string NumCta
        {
            get { return _NumCta; }
            set { _NumCta = value; }
        }

        private string _Desc;
        public string Desc
        {
            get { return _Desc; }
            set { _Desc = value; }
        }

        private string _subctade;
        public string SubCtaDe
        {
            get { return _subctade; }
            set { _subctade = value; }
        }

        private string _Nivel;
        public string Nivel
        {
            get { return _Nivel; }
            set { _Nivel = value; }
        }
        private string _Natur;
        public string Natur
        {
            get { return _Natur; }
            set { _Natur = value; }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "CodAgrup = " + CodAgrup + ", NumCta = " + NumCta + ", Desc = " + Desc + ", SubCtaDe = " + SubCtaDe + ", Nivel = " + Nivel + ", Natur = " + Natur;
        }
  #endregion
    }
```

and I have Create an XML from these properties, so first I have to fill the properties, then i got the next method i want to use to fill the properties, first question is, **is it correct the way Im using to  fill the properties?**

Then I should retreive the data and write it on an XML file so I convert properties data into a list and then just write them as atributes but when i Debug, I get that the list is empty, **Why is that?** **what could be the best way to do it?**

```
//Insert n data on properties
static void cuenta(string codagroup, string numcta, string desc, string subctade, string nivel, string natur)
        {
            Ctas cuentas = new Ctas();
            int x = 0;
          while (cuentas.CodAgrup != null)
          { 
                cuentas.CodAgrup.Insert(x, "codagroup");
                cuentas.NumCta.Insert(x, "numcta");
                cuentas.Desc.Insert(x, "desc");
                cuentas.SubCtaDe.Insert(x,"subctade");
                cuentas.Nivel.Insert(x, "nivel");
                cuentas.Natur.Insert(x, "natur");
                x = x + 1;
            }
        }

//Converting propierties data into list
 List<string> coda = cuentas.CodAgrup.GetType().GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
                List<string> ncta = cuentas.NumCta.GetType().GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
                List<string> desc = cuentas.Desc.GetType().GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
                List<string> subdes = cuentas.SubCtaDe.GetType().GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
                List<string> nivel = cuentas.Nivel.GetType().GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
                List<string> natur = cuentas.Natur.GetType().GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
//Create XML from data in list´s
 for (int i = 0; i < coda.Count; i++)
                {
                    xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("CodAgrup", coda[i]);
                    xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("NumCta", ncta[i]);
                    xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Desc", desc[i]);
//write the atribute when property data exists.
                    if (cuentas.SubCtaDe != null)
                    {
                        xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("SubCtaDe", subdes[i]);
                    }
                    xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Nivel", nivel[i]);
                    xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Natur", natur[i]);
                    xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();

                }
```

Comment: The code inside your while loop will never execute because `cuentas.CodAgrup` will be null if you don't initialize it after instantiating `cuentas`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is confusing, but if I understand it right, here is the first error I see:

```
  Ctas cuentas = new Ctas();
  int x = 0;
  while (cuentas.CodAgrup != null)   // cuentas.CodAgrup is null from the beginning!
  { 
        cuentas.CodAgrup.Insert(x, "codagroup");
        cuentas.NumCta.Insert(x, "numcta");
        cuentas.Desc.Insert(x, "desc");
        cuentas.SubCtaDe.Insert(x,"subctade");
        cuentas.Nivel.Insert(x, "nivel");
        cuentas.Natur.Insert(x, "natur");
        x = x + 1;
  }
```

Since you are looking at a brand-new `Ctas` object, and there is no code to initialize the `CodAgrup` property, it will have the default value of `null`, so the code never enters the `while` loop.

Even if it DID, I suspect it would be an endless loop, because you're `Insert`ing a literal value into a string property, and there is no condition I see where `cuentas.CodAgrup` will ever be null.

As for your XML generation, why not just use the built in `XmlSerializer` class?  Even if you require a specific format, there are attributes that let you customize the XML that is generated.

Comment: you a re right,there should be none quotes, I got an idea on what to do, by the way then, how to fill the properties given unknow number of data to enter?.